# GET request with headers using keep-alive connection under python

Tags: python, get, http-headers, keep-alive

I want to make a connection to http://mysite.org using GET method keeping connection alive and sending an user-agent header to the server. I know I should use urlgrabber or smth like that but I need the actual code actually.
Please help me friends..
THANK YOU

```
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(urlparse(url)[1])
conn.request("GET", urlparse(url)[2])
conn.putheader("Referer", referer)
conn.endheaders()
r1 = conn.getresponse()
```

whats wrong with that??

Comment: What error do you get? What is `url` to start with?

Answer (score -2):

Use `httplib`

The Python docs page has examples there.
http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html